# Unity doesnt create or open projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, hub

It worked fine for a few years, but recently I updated my unity hub to 3.4.1 but it worked properly, until today, I restarted my laptop, ran unity as administrator, nothing works, when I click to open a project it just shows that its loading but it doesn't open, did anyone experience same problem?
Thanks!
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1L0V34b9Jnsih-8PofBirrgoaJe9CJrYb?usp=sharing (logs)

[image: the infinite loading]

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening Unity editor on its own and loading the project the old school way.

If you google you'll see various "fixes, from logging out and logging back in, reinstalling hub and even returning the license and reapplying it. But Unity Hub's [log](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039118331-I-have-been-asked-to-provide-a-log-file-where-do-I-find-this-) will most likely tell you which case it is. Look for errors there.

Comment: I tried signing out and in, reinstalling twice, nothing worked:
here are the logs:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1L0V34b9Jnsih-8PofBirrgoaJe9CJrYb?usp=sharing

Comment: Thats the logs files, there are multiple, i have no idea which one is needed, sorry

Comment: Looking through info-log.json, I searched for your project's name.
I can see some errors.
1)  One error mentioning a NOT_A_VALID_PROJECT error code while adding the project to the hub
and 
Error while opening project: MISSING_EDITOR_VERSION

Normally though it should have asked you with a popup whether to install the missing editor version or use another and give you the options. This sort of error appears in my logs too.

I also see an error from the LicensingClient :Failed with ipc error type: PipeIsNotOpen
Means it can't verify your license, could be why they don't open.

Comment: I'm also seeing you trying to install the version, but there are some errors a bit further that say "User did not grant permission.',\n    message: 'The Hub does not have proper permissions to install Unity." as if you denied a permission popup for the installation to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Unity Hub 3, on older versions (2.0) everything worked fine.
After a little investigation, I realized that everything is working correctly, it's just that the Hub will not help you connect to the servers to check the license.
I solve my problem using VPN.

UPD: I have such a problem because I live in a sanctioned region in which unity services do not work.